# Ace Editor synchronous scrolling

Tags: jquery, vertical-scrolling, ace-editor, synchronization

I have two simultaneous Ace editor sessions running side-by-side, I'm trying to synchronize vertical scrolling of both editors. I found a simple jQuery method that works with normal Divs, but how can I adapt it to work correctly with Ace?

**jQuery method:**

```
$("#editor1").scroll(function () { 
    $("#editor2").scrollTop($("#editor1").scrollTop());
    $("#editor2").scrollLeft($("#editor1").scrollLeft());
});

$("#editor2").scroll(function () { 
    $("#editor1").scrollTop($("#editor2").scrollTop());
    $("#editor1").scrollLeft($("#editor2").scrollLeft());
});
```

Obviously, the above method doesn't work with Ace. I've been looking through the Ace API here: **[Virtual Renderer](http://ace.ajax.org/api/virtual_renderer.html)** for a solution, but I can't even seem to set any callback function when scrolling on the editor.

There's a reference to scrollbar in the API **[Here](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=api&api=scrollbar)**, but can't seem to get it to do anything. Iv'e tried testing it like so...

```
editor.ScrollBar.on('scroll', function() {
    alert('Callback?');
});
```

Could somebody please help me on this one? :) Thanks.

**EDIT**

The solution below does work, but (in my case) it crashes the browser (Chrome) almost immediately. I set a timeout function on it to limit how quickly it can fire, but it still inevitably crashes. Ideas?

```
editor.getSession().on('changeScrollTop', function(scroll) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        editor2.getSession().setScrollTop(scroll);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Info: I added a workaround for the crash happening when scrolling to top

Finally got it :

```
editor.getSession().on('changeScrollTop', function(scroll) {
  editor2.getSession().setScrollTop(parseInt(scroll) || 0)
});
```

You can see a working demo [here on CodePen](http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/fzucK)

Comment: I tried this, it did seem to work until the browser crashed.    editor.getSession().on('changeScrollTop', function(scroll) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  editor2.getSession().setScrollTop(scroll);
 }, 1000);
});

I set a timeout function on it to stop it, but, this is not a great solution really.

Answer (score 3):

there is a bug in ace that makes your code to go into infinite loop
scroll isn't actually a number but an object and editor.session.setScrollTop({}) results into scrollTop = NaN. Following code works fine

```
s1 = editor1.session
s2 = editor2.session

s1.on('changeScrollTop', function() {
  s2.setScrollTop(s1.getScrollTop())
});

s2.on('changeScrollTop', function() {
  s1.setScrollTop(s2.getScrollTop())
});
```